# Not able to execute git commands in Command Prompt even after setting path in system variables

Tags: windows, git

> D:\Git\bin\git.exe
>  D:\Git\cmd\git.exe

path visible in git bash after executing 'where git' command

> D:\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbUSm.png)

Comment: Try restarting the Bash after configuring the path.

Answer (score 1):

The path should be `D:\Git\bin` and not `D:\Git\bin\git.exe`.

This adds all programs inside the `D:\bin` directory to the path.